# How can the polynomial $x^7+1$ be factored in $\mathbb F_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

I want to factorize this polynomial $x^{7}+1$.

The result that I expect is $(x+1)(x^{3}+x+1)(x^{3}+x^{2}+x+1)$

What is the best way to proceed?

As it seems the factorization is conducted in $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Why do you expect that?

Comment: $(1 + x) (1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4 - x^5 + x^6)$.

Comment: It is part of a polynomial coding problem. I was given that this polynomial is equal to that factorised polynomial. However I dont get how they got this result, and I dont want to take it for granted... Also we need 3rd degree factors for the polynomial generator.. I think that the 6th degree (Thanks David G. Stork) can be analyzed further.. Will try this..

Comment: What is the coefficient ring for your polynomials?  Mayby your factorization holds over $\Bbb Z_2$?  I haven't checked yet . . .

Comment: The factorization you have given is incorrect, both over $\Bbb{Q}$ and over any finite field.

Comment: Over $\Bbb F_2$, the factorisation is $(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)$.

Comment: Lord Shark the Unknown I think you are correct. Since this code is binary, the terms will get eliminated .. It now makes sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^7+1=(x+1)(x^6-x^5+x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^6+x^4+x^3+x^5+x^3+x^2+x^3+x+1)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^3(x^3+x+1)+x^2(x^3+x+1)+x^3+x+1)=$$
$$=(x+1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1).$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 2):

The polynomial $x^7+1$ has a factor $x+1$, which can easily be seen from the fact that $(-1)^7+1=0$. The remainder is the $14$th cyclotomic polynomial, which is irreducible as all cyclotomic polynomials are.

Comment: But wasn’t OP dealing with $\Bbb F_2$-polynomials only?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this isn't right. $\Phi_n$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, but as Michael Rozenberg's answer shows, $\Phi_{14}$ is not irreducible over $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: @YiFan Indeed it isn't irreducible over $\Bbb{F}_2$, but there was no mention of any field in the original question.

Comment: @Servaes I see, I didn't check the edit history. My bad.